# JQuery Themes issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Ok so I am trying to install a UI theme but the images are not showing.
the image folder is at same level of .css
here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>
```

Comment: use `href="css/dot-luv/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css"` - and not `/css/dot-luv/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css`
`

Comment: Does not work still.. :) its actually how I had it first before I went trying to fix the issue

Comment: what is the directory structure of the images file ?

Comment: it is inside dot-luv folder alongside the .css files

Comment: any reason you are using `jquery-ui-1.10.2` for js and `jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css` for css ?

Comment: I assumed you had to use the provided files with the downloaded theme? Im very new to jquery, just started today and I want to get this theme working. The link is here :
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/  and click on gallery

Answer (score 0):

Go into the jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css file where the images are being called and put "../" in front of the path. It that doesnt work  put this "../../".

Comment: I can't seem to find where they are called. Its def the images though as the hosted version works fine.

Comment: go into your editor and press ctrl + F and look for background image or png.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/dot-luv/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css" />
```

verify the url image

Comment: It Did not work. Since its an official theme could it be an issue with the actual release or just something on my side?